# Use trac with separate board for tasks and bugs

Tags: project-management, trac, bug-tracking

I'm starting a new software proyect and I wanted to use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) to manage it. Mostly because I love it's wiki and I love the way [django use it](https://docs.djangoproject.com).

One thing I'd like to avoid is to pollute the development board with bug reports and viceversa. A quick round on google left me bare handed so I'd like to ask if any of you have experience setting up trac with different boards, one for regular planning and other for bug tracking.

Opinions?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by "development board". Are you looking for a multi-project solution, or a way to have separate views within a single project? Trac supports [multi-project installations](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects#HostingMultipleProjects), and you can link between the projects using [InterTracLinks](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/InterTrac).

Comment: If you fear distraction by bug issues, you could utilize ticket types to focus no reports for your tasks alone. I prefer having all issues in one place, but still be able to filter bug and/or enhancement requests out as you see need to do. Trac can do all that with very few report customization, as long as you can make a clear definition of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to organise it and there are several possible ways. In my opinion the best is to define two different ticket type groups (see http://{yourTrac}/admin/ticket/type), one for the plan and the other for bug handling:

1. plan:

   - 'workpackage' for grouping
   - 'enhancement'
   - 'modification'
   - 'task'
   - => insert tickets of type enhancement, modification and task as children to tickets of type workpackage (e.g. using MasterTicketsPlugin)
2. bug tracking:

   - 'bug'

Then use the Trac query language all over your ticket queries and Trac plugins to separate by ticket type, and insert them separated in your wiki pages and milestone wiki-language descriptions, e.g.:

```
[[TicketQuery(group=type,format=progress,type=enhancement|modification|task)]]
[[TicketQuery(group=type,format=progress,type=bug)]]

[[BurndownChart(milestone=v1.0,label=Plan,startdate=2014-10-20,enddate=2015-05-25,type=enhancement|modification|task)]]
[[BurndownChart(milestone=v1.0,label=Bugs,startdate=2014-10-20,enddate=2015-05-25,type=bug)]]

[[WorkloadChart(milestone=v1.0,type=enhancement|modification|task)]]> 
[[WorkloadChart(milestone=v1.0,type=bug)]]

[[TracJSGanttChart(milestone=v1.0,type=workpackage|enhancement|modification|task)]]
[[TracJSGanttChart(milestone=v1.0,type=workpackage|bug)]]
```

One approach is to add the bug tickets as child tickets to the appropriate tickets of the plan if they are the result of the development and fall out during the testing period.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to keep the list of tickets that represent your development plan for forthcoming release(s) separate from the untidy thicket of tickets that represent issues being encountered by users of the current release, how about using ticket "milestone"?  So, "bug" reports would be opened in the "current" milestone, task planning (for potentially multiple future releases) would be associated with non-current milestone(s).  I assert this allows for clearer description of items in both the current and the forthcoming release.

Someone opens a ticket complaining about how things work right now.  If you decide you should address it for current users, you leave it in the current milestone (though you might reclassify it a "task" or an "enhancement").  If you decide it must wait for another release, you move it into a forthcoming milestone, but can choose to leave it called a "bug", it doesn't have to be reclassified as a "task".

Likewise, when you're testing the unreleased code and find a problem, you can call it a "bug", but in the forthcoming milestone; again, it doesn't have to be a "task" just to be considered part of the development plan.